# Applying iScroll on ColorBox Popup

Tags: javascript, zend-framework, iscroll

I am a new developer in PHP. I am trying to apply iScroll on colorbox popup but the scroll is not showing on popup. When I press F12 the scroll shows on popup automatically. I don't know why?

Comment: More information on what you have attempted would help

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply iScroll on complete event of colorbox. That will solve your problem.

```
function onModalComplete()/*: void */
{
    if(!window.modalScroller)
    {
        window.modalScroller = new iScroll('cboxLoadedContent', { hScroll: false, bounce: false, hideScrollbar: true });
    }
}
```